# Uncompressing Strings to Strings with Snappy in Java

Tags: java, snappy

I am trying to compress `Strings`, writing them in files (as `Strings`) and uncompressing those files.
For compressing, I have written this function:

```
public static String compress(String s) throws IOException {
    byte[] by = Snappy.compress(s, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return new String(by, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

and then, for uncompressing,

```
public static String uncompress(String s) throws IOException {
    byte[] by = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return Snappy.uncompressString(by, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

But I get `FAILED_TO_UNCOMPRESS(5)`, and by looking at the data, `Snappy.compress(s, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` does not give the same result as applying `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` to the data compressed with my `compress` function.
Do you know why? And how I could compress and uncompress to `Strings`? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you storing the result in a `String` object in your `compress` method? Strings are not suitable for storing arbitrary bytes. Make the `compress` method return the `byte[]` instead of a `String`, and make the `uncompress` method take the `byte[]` as an argument instead of a `String`. If you really need to store the bytes in a string, then you'll have to use something like base 64 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

The compression results in bytes and you need to store them as bytes until you decompress it again. You can't convert the compressed bytes back into a `String` (the `byte[]` might not even contain valid UTF-8).

Now you're going to ask "but how will I save the compressed `String` into a file?". Well, you're going to save it into a *binary* file, i.e. writing bytes instead of Strings. That means you can't edit the file in notepad or even look at the file (well you can, but it will be a garbled mess).

Answer (score 0):

This does work, use `Base64.getEncoder()` and `Base64.getDecoder()`

```
BitShuffle.unshuffleIntArray(Snappy.uncompress(Base64.getDecoder().decode(new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(Snappy.compress(BitShuffle.shuffle(new int[]{1, 2, 3})))))));
```

Although snappy is using less space in bytes rather than Base64 string.
Also encoding/decoding adds ~45% performance, dispensable overhead, that snappy is trying to reduce.